# I can't add songs to lxmusic

Tags: sound, 13.04, music, lxde, openbox

I'm using lxmusic to play sounds. When I try to import files using the bottom left button, the files appear in the list for one second and then they disappear. Running it from the console only produces this message: `** (lxmusic:2640): WARNING **: on_playback_volume_changed: couldn't get volume, output plugin not loaded`. I've tried adding music using the button and by selecting the files then dragging them to the window. Any help? I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 Minimal.

Comment: What is the operating system?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Ubuntu 13.04 Minimal.

Comment: Please incorporate whatever additional information you provide into the question so that people can get the picture by reading the question itself rather than having to go the various comments.

Answer (score 1):

Running `sudo apt-get purge lxmusic` then `sudo apt-get install lxmusic` worked for me. Now I can add songs to lxmusic.

Answer (score 0):

Install `xmms` plugins.

LXMusic is based off of xmms2, and uses it as a backend for playback.  Source: [LXDE blog](http://blog.lxde.org/?p=136).
Ubuntu has a lot of these plugins in its repositories.  You can see a list of them by going to the terminal, typing `sudo apt-get install xmms2-plugin-`, and then pressing the `Tab` key twice.  You can install all you see there by adding a `*` to the end, and pressing `Enter`.

Comment: I installed the plugins, started lxmusic, tried to add the music, and got this error: `(lxmusic:4877): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strrstr_len: assertion 'haystack != NULL' failed` + `Segmentation fault`

Comment: I'm afraid that's something to check in the code. I can't seem to find any information on it, either.  If you're using the latest version of LXMusic, I'd file a bug on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxmusic).

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get purge lxmusic` then `sudo apt-get install lxmusic`. I can add music now.

Answer (score 0):

I installed xmms2 and all problems went away - I can add music files to LXMusic and play.  I am running Debian 11.6.0.